# How to share code between classes that do not have the same parent?

Tags: php, php-5.2

I have classes A, B of external library and my classes A2 extends A, and B2 extends B. Code of class A2 and B2 is exactly the same. Can I share it? Code do some job and calls parent functions:

```
class A2 extends A
{
  function func1($var1, $var2,...)
  {
     ...
     ... Do some job
     ...
     return parent::func1($var1, $var2,...);
  }
  function func2($var1, $var2,...)
  {
     ...
     ... Do some job
     ...
     return parent::func2($var1, $var2,...);
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
}

class B2 extends B
{
  function func1($var1, $var2,...)
  {
     ...
     ... Do some job
     ...
     return parent::func1($var1, $var2,...);
  }
  function func2($var1, $var2,...)
  {
     ...
     ... Do some job
     ...
     return parent::func2($var1, $var2,...);
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

I am stuck with PHP 5.2.x and `allow_url_include=off` (because of customer restrictions),

Comment: Can you change A and B so that they both extend the same class, and then put your common code there?

Comment: Can't you use Strategy here - that is, define this overlapping code in some other class that will be used (by aggregation or with DI) by both A2 and B2?

Comment: Question:  Is there some reason to have A2 and B2 extend A and B, respectively, other than to make it easy to call their methods?  Are you going to be treating an A1 *as* an A, for example?

Comment: PHP 5.4 and Traits... gotta love legacy work. Makes you sweat a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If A2 and B2 are *exactly* the same, then turn that into its own class rather than having it extend existing classes.  You can then pass an object of that class into whatever other objects actually need to use it.

See also: [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it might be a good idea to look at this from another direction. Class A and B have different code, but A2 and B2 have the same code, so we'll refer to that chunk of code as C.  What you need are a class A2 and B2, where A2 has functionality from A and C, and B2 has functionality from B and C.  Can you make C a superclass of A and B?  Then you just use those two classes directly, without duplicating code.